Unity 2d Isometric Game - Sprite Overlap issue
I'm making a 2d isometric game in Unity, but my sprites don't render well when they overlap.
For example, in this image the skeleton monster renders behind the dragon, but in an isometric view we expect the dragon to be behind the skeleton monster. Units move across the board, so in a different scenario the skeleton might be behind the dragon. I need the rendering order to be decided by their x y coordinate, in some way.


Does this answer your question? If not, please edit your question to walk us through the steps to recreate this scene the way you've built it in your project.

Since I haven't heard back in a couple of days, I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate. If you're unable to solve your problem using the advice in this Q&A thread, please edit your question to clarify where you've gotten stuck. Once we have that information, we can re-open this post for answers.
